# yes or no always gets changed to true or false sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I've an **yes/no column** and I use **InfoPath** to enter data and a SharePoint designer workflow to send emails. But when I get the email it always **changes the yes value to true and no value to false**.

I then changed the format to **1** and **0** in infopath but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Yes/No fields are boolean values: true/false. They will never display Yes or No as text, so you will need to set these programmatically within your workflow. Create a workflow variable for the "Yes" and "No" values and replace the yesNoField in your email. Example:

```
yesNoVariable = "No"

if yesNoField equals True

   yesNoVariable = "Yes"
```

Or, you can replace your checkbox with a choice field using the values Yes/No.

Comment: at the movement i have added it like that, but when i see the data entered in sharepoint is yes or no so i thought it might be possible.